# HTML 5 Canvas performance in IE 9 on Windows 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-9, html5-canvas

This is an HTML 5 Canvas application.  It's a pretty standard "designer" application where the user adds objects to a layout, moves them around, and edits their properties.

It works very well, but it turns out to have real performance problems in IE 9 on Windows 7.  I would appreciate any thoughts!

- Operations often take 10 seconds instead of the usual 2 seconds.
- Also, after using the application a little while, the browser gives an error message that the host "is not responding", giving options Recover Webpage and X.  Once that starts to happen, it happens for every user action including the File menu, and I can only get out of it by editing the URL location text.  In particular, it generally happens on any attempt to use the browser's profiler in Developer Tools.  This is obviously frustrating, but it may also be a clue.  I wondered if there might be pending synchronous AJAX calls, as suggested by this error message, but capturing the network traffic using Developer Tools suggests that all calls are complete.
- The problem seems specific to this combination of browser and OS.  IE 9 on Windows Server 2008 behaves OK, and so do Firefox and Chrome on Windows 7.  The problem is the same for 32-bit or 64-bit IE.
- Most of these operations have a server-side component too.  For example, adding a text object makes an AJAX call to serve an image for the object.  The server API is implemented as a small TurboGears application which uses ImageMagick for the image processing.  But rough profiling indicates that nothing unusual is happening on the server side.  This suggests that the problem really is in the JavaScript.
- The Task Manager shows the browser using CPU of 90% or more when the application is running.  This is true for any browser, not just IE 9.  This is likely because of the tight rendering loop in the application, so one idea we had was to redraw the canvas less often.  Unfortunately this did not seem to help.  requestAnimationFrame seems like a good idea, but is not supported in IE 9.
- A colleague suggested that using the Google Chrome Frame plug-in might help.  It might be an acceptable solution, but I haven't tried it yet.
- I found some advice to turn on the Control Panel option "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering", but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Link? IE 10 is newer and therefor faster. Chrome Frame should help, because it uses Chrome's faster Javascript implementation.

Comment: Without seeing the code or its "operations" it is impossible to tell why it would be this slow. I suggest you repeat the problem with an isolated test case on jsfiddle.net. You probably need to break down your drawing operations to several steps and give CPU time to the browser main thread.

Comment: Or alternatively... as suggested, just make IE users install Google Chrome Frame http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/chrome-frame-faq

Comment: @tjameson, I may be able to get the client's permission to post a link to the application, so I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have noticed: It seems the canvas is much slower in IE if you start drawing on it when it's not in the document.

So I do `document.body.appendChild(canvasEl)` before I draw. You can even make the canvas element `dislay: none;` but at least it should be in the body.

Update: It seems that for Chrome and Firefox, appending the canvas to the body is slower. So if you don't need it to be added to the body, don't add it for Chrome and Firefox.